# Extending packages and access to the content

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica

I continue work on understanding how to best divide code in library and application. In a few previous posts I have worked with a toy example DEMO_xx library with application dxx_app7. Below is a slightly updated version to cover the question here. I have included the possibility to add a sensor to the harvest tank.

Now I want to understand how to in application code bring in information from the application Medium7 that is extended from the library Medium2 and use that fully in a new component model in the application.

What I understand is that if you import a package that is extended from another package you only get what is the “latest” package and NOT what is built up from through extensions and what is aggregated total Medium7 information.

This fact is illustrated in the example by changing the constant SensorX.component from C that works  to A or B that does not work.

However, if I make a local instance of Medium7 THEN  I get the complete information of Medium7. I can do that in SensorX as marked Question 1 - alt 2.
I can also do this choice of substrate to measure out in the configuration of the system and marked Question 1 alt 3. This is more readable code I think.

1. But how do I make all of the content of Medium7 available locally? Must I define locally a new constant for every constant I need as I show here with sensorX.component?  Generally you may want to in a model have access to various properties of the medium and that is convenient to put in the package Medium
2. Also I wish I could import a connector LiquidCon adapted for Medium7 instead of writing that code once again in package Sensor7. Import as suggested does not work. Is there another way? I have only tested the code in JModelica 2.4 and it might be a bug?

Would appreciate some input on these two questions. / Jan Peter

Below the application code d12_app7 that is of interest for the questions and then the associated library DEMO_v12. I have marked up with comments changes of code for the two questions and as the code stands it is for question 1 alt 1.

```
    encapsulated package d12_app7 

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        package Medium7
            import M2 = DEMO_v12.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name = "Seven components"                      "Medium name", 
                nc = 7                                          "Number of substances",
                mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30,40,50,60,70})              "Substance weight",
                redeclare type Concentration = Real[nc]         "Substance conc");
            constant Integer C = 3                              "Substance index";
            constant Integer D = 4                              "Substance index";  
            constant Integer E = 5                              "Substance index";  
            constant Integer F = 6                              "Substance index";  
            constant Integer G = 7                              "Substance index";  
        end Medium7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     New sensor introduced in this application for measurement of substance A 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Sensor7
            connector LiquidCon
                Medium7.Concentration c                         "Substance conc";
                flow Real F (unit="m3/s")                       "Flow rate";
            end LiquidCon;

            model SensorX
    //          import d12_app7.Equipment7.LiquidCon;                 // Question 2
                import d12_app7.Medium7.*;                            // Question 1 - alt 1
                constant Integer component = C;                       // Question 1 - alt 1  
    //          constant Integer component = d12_app7.Medium7.A;      // Question 1 - alt 2
                LiquidCon probe;
                RealOutput out;
            equation
                probe.F = 0;
                out = probe.c[component];
            end SensorX;    
        end Sensor7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Adaptation of library DEMO_v12 to Medium7  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment7
            import DEMO_v12.Equipment;
            extends Equipment(redeclare package Medium=Medium7);
        end Equipment7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import DEMO_v12.Control;

        model Test
            Equipment7.Medium medium;        // Instance not necessary but helpful for user interface
            Equipment7.PumpType pump;
            Equipment7.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment7.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Sensor7.SensorX sensor;                             // Question 1 alt 1 and 2
    //      Sensor7.SensorX sensor(component = medium.A);       // Question 1 alt 3    
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
            connect(sensor.probe, harvesttank.port);
        end Test;

    end d12_app7;
```

And finally the library code DEMO_v12

```
    package DEMO_v12

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        package Medium2
            replaceable constant String name = "Two components"    "Medium name";
            replaceable constant Integer nc = 2                    "Number of substances";
            replaceable type Concentration = Real[nc]              "Substance conc";
            replaceable constant Real[nc] mw = {10, 20}            "Substance weight";  
            constant Integer A = 1                                 "Substance index";
            constant Integer B = 2                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium2;

        package Medium3 
            import M2 = DEMO_v12.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name="Three components"                           "Medium name",
                 nc=3                                              "Number of substances",
                 mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30})                            "Substance weight",
                 redeclare type Concentration = Real[nc]           "Substance conc");
            constant Integer C = 3                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium3;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Equipment dependent on the medium  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment
            replaceable package Medium
            end Medium;

            connector LiquidCon
                Medium.Concentration c                             "Substance conc";
                flow Real F (unit="m3/s")                          "Flow rate";
            end LiquidCon;

            model PumpType
                LiquidCon inlet, outlet;                                                     
                RealInput Fsp;
            equation
                inlet.F = Fsp;                                         
                connect(outlet, inlet);                          
            end PumpType;

            model FeedtankType
                LiquidCon outlet;                                  
                constant Integer medium_nc = size(outlet.c,1);
                parameter Real[medium_nc] c_in (each unit="kg/m3") 
                                = {1.0*k for k in 1:medium_nc}     "Feed inlet conc";                        
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 100               "Initial feed volume";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Feed volume";
            equation    
                for i in 1:medium_nc loop
                    outlet.c[i] = c_in[i];
                end for;
                der(V) = outlet.F;               
            end FeedtankType;

            model HarvesttankType
                LiquidCon inlet, port;                                   
                constant Integer medium_nc = size(inlet.c,1);
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 1.0   "Initial harvest liquid volume";
                parameter Real[medium_nc] m_0 
                      (each unit="kg/m3") = zeros(medium_nc)       "Initial substance mass";
                Real[medium_nc] c                                  "Substance conc";
                Real[medium_nc] m 
                      (start=m_0, each fixed=true)                 "Substance mass";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Harvest liquid volume";
            equation
                for i in 1:medium_nc loop
                    der(m[i]) = inlet.c[i]*inlet.F;
                    c[i] = m[i]/V;
                    port.c[i] = c[i];
                end for;
                der(V) = inlet.F;               
            end HarvesttankType;
        end Equipment;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    //     Control 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Control
            block FixValueType
                RealOutput out;
                parameter Real val=0;
            equation
                out = val;
            end FixValueType;
        end Control;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //  package Equipment3 = Equipment(redeclare package Medium=Medium3);   // Just shorter version

        package Equipment3
            import DEMO_v12.Equipment;
            extends Equipment(redeclare package Medium=Medium3);
        end Equipment3;

        model Test
            Equipment3.Medium medium;
            Equipment3.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment3.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Equipment3.PumpType pump;
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
        end Test;

    end DEMO_v12;
```

Comment: I just corrected d12_app7 and model SensorX. The import statement for LiquidCon in Question 2 is now correct. The code still does not work when this alternative is made active - so the question 2 remains!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Adeel! 
The Dymola error log made me do the following changes to the code:

1. DEMO_v20 here I eliminated the instantiation of medium - forgot it see 3) above
2. DEMO_v20 here I now get the size of the models from Medium.nc instead of through the connector and size of c.
3. D20_app7 here I now in the procedure of adaptation of package Equipment, first import, and then extend and adapt to Medium7.

The updated code DEMO_v22 and d22_app7 now works with both JModelica and OpenModelica. Would be good to have it tested in Dymola too

Updated code DEMO_v22.mo

```
    package DEMO_v22

        // Here I have put together a small demo-library to illustrate questions
        // around structuring handling of medium. The key structures are taken
        // from MSL fluid, I think it is fair to say.

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        partial package MediumBase
            constant String name                                   "Medium name";
            constant Integer nc                                    "Number of substances";
            replaceable type Concentration = Real[nc]              "Substance conc";        
        end MediumBase;

        package Medium2 
            extends MediumBase
                (name="Two components",
                 nc=2);
            constant Real[nc] mw = {10, 20}                        "Substance weight";  
            constant Integer A = 1                                 "Substance index";
            constant Integer B = 2                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium2;

        package Medium3 
            import M2 = DEMO_v22.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name="Three components"                           "Medium name",
                 nc=3                                              "Number of substances",
                 mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30})                            "Substance weight");
            constant Integer C = 3                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium3;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Equipment dependent on the medium  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment
            replaceable package Medium = MediumBase 
                constrainedby MediumBase;

            connector LiquidCon
                Medium.Concentration c                             "Substance conc";
                flow Real F (unit="m3/s")                          "Flow rate";
            end LiquidCon;

            model PumpType
                LiquidCon inlet, outlet;                                                     
                RealInput Fsp;
            equation
                inlet.F = Fsp;                                         
                connect(outlet, inlet);                          
            end PumpType;

            model FeedtankType
                LiquidCon outlet;                                  
                parameter Real[Medium.nc] c_in (each unit="kg/m3") 
                                = {1.0*k for k in 1:Medium.nc}     "Feed inlet conc";                        
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 100               "Initial feed volume";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Feed volume";
            equation    
                for i in 1:Medium.nc loop
                    outlet.c[i] = c_in[i];
                end for;
                der(V) = outlet.F;               
            end FeedtankType;

            model HarvesttankType
                LiquidCon inlet, port;
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 1.0   "Initial harvest liquid volume";
                parameter Real[Medium.nc] m_0 
                      (each unit="kg/m3") = zeros(Medium.nc)       "Initial substance mass";
                Real[Medium.nc] c                                  "Substance conc";
                Real[Medium.nc] m 
                      (start=m_0, each fixed=true)                 "Substance mass";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Harvest liquid volume";
            equation
                for i in 1:Medium.nc loop
                    der(m[i]) = inlet.c[i]*inlet.F;
                    c[i] = m[i]/V;
                    port.c[i] = c[i];
                end for;
                der(V) = inlet.F;               
            end HarvesttankType;
        end Equipment;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    //     Control 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Control
            block FixValueType
                RealOutput out;
                parameter Real val=0;
            equation
                out = val;
            end FixValueType;
        end Control;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Adaptation of package Equipment to Medium3 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment3
            extends DEMO_v22.Equipment(redeclare package Medium=Medium3);
        end Equipment3;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        model Test
            package medium = DEMO_v22.Medium3;                     // Not accessible in FMU though
            constant String name = medium.name;                    // But name here is now accessible
            Equipment3.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment3.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Equipment3.PumpType pump;
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
        end Test;

    end DEMO_v22;
```

and updated application code d22_app7.mo

```
    encapsulated package d22_app7 

        // Here I put together an application for 7 substances - print 8 pt
        // and import code from the library DEMO.

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        package Medium7
            import M2 = DEMO_v22.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name = "Seven components"                            "Medium name", 
                nc = 7                                                "Number of substances",
                mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30,40,50,60,70})                    "Substance weight");
            constant Integer C = 3                                    "Substance index";
            constant Integer D = 4                                    "Substance index";    
            constant Integer E = 5                                    "Substance index";    
            constant Integer F = 6                                    "Substance index";    
            constant Integer G = 7                                    "Substance index";    
        end Medium7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Adaptation of library DEMO_v22 to Medium7 and including a new model SensorX 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment7
            import DEMO_v22.Equipment;
            extends Equipment(redeclare package Medium=Medium7);
            model SensorX
                LiquidCon probe;
                RealOutput out;
                constant Integer component                            "Component measured";         
            equation
                probe.F = 0;
                out = probe.c[component];
            end SensorX;            
        end Equipment7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import DEMO_v22.Control;

        model Test
            package medium = Medium7;                                // Not accessible in FMU though
            constant String name = medium.name;                      // But name here is accessible
            Equipment7.PumpType pump;
            Equipment7.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment7.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Equipment7.SensorX sensor(component = medium.G);               
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
            connect(sensor.probe, harvesttank.port);
        end Test;

    end d22_app7;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also on this post recently got some help from people related to Modelon-JModelica and to OpenModelica - thank you! Below answers and comments as well as updated code.

1. To make content of Medium7 available we can (likely) do as in the presented code.  In my new code I decide what substance to measure not until configuration of the Test model. Therefore I in the model SensorX make a declaration constant Integer component without any value. Note a constant can only be given a value once.
2. To avoid writing the code of LiquidCon a second time it is better to put the code of the sensor model in the extension of package Equipment where adaptation is made to Medium7.
3. In the model Test we need to have access to the mnemonics of components. The construction in the code with an instance of a package is not allowed in Modelica (but still works in JModelica and OpenModelica). A generally accepted way to do is given in the new code. Note that this solution makes the content of the actual Medium not accessible through FMU. To get that accessibility local instances need to be made of various medium constants in the model, as done with name.
4. I have in DEMO_v20.Medium2 taken away “replaceable” in front of constants, and the technique to just give these Medium constants different values in Medium3 is allowed since Modelica 3.2 (but not in 3.1) according to Hans Olsson in a previous post response.
5. I have in DEMO_v20 introduced a partial MediumBase and then Medium2 extends from that and MeiumBase also is constraining type for the formal parameter Medium for package Equipment.

The code works for JModelica both running DEMO_v20 alone with the Test example for three substances and together with the application code for seven substances. In OpenModelica only the Test example for three substances work, however.

Would appreciate help to get the code working in OpenModelica and to check it in Dymolas as well.

Library code DEMO_v20

```
    package DEMO_v20

        // Here I have put together a small demo-library to illustrate questions
        // around structuring handling of medium. The key structures are taken
        // from MSL fluid, I think it is fair to say.

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        partial package MediumBase
            constant String name                                   "Medium name";
            constant Integer nc                                    "Number of substances";
            replaceable type Concentration = Real[nc]              "Substance conc";        
        end MediumBase;

        package Medium2 
            extends MediumBase
                (name="Two components",
                 nc=2);
            constant Real[nc] mw = {10, 20}                        "Substance weight";  
            constant Integer A = 1                                 "Substance index";
            constant Integer B = 2                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium2;

        package Medium3 
            import M2 = DEMO_v20.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name="Three components"                           "Medium name",
                 nc=3                                              "Number of substances",
                 mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30})                            "Substance weight");
            constant Integer C = 3                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium3;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Equipment dependent on the medium  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment
            replaceable package Medium = MediumBase 
                constrainedby MediumBase;

            connector LiquidCon
                Medium.Concentration c                             "Substance conc";
                flow Real F (unit="m3/s")                          "Flow rate";
            end LiquidCon;

            model PumpType
                LiquidCon inlet, outlet;                                                     
                RealInput Fsp;
            equation
                inlet.F = Fsp;                                         
                connect(outlet, inlet);                          
            end PumpType;

            model FeedtankType
                LiquidCon outlet;                                  
                constant Integer medium_nc = size(outlet.c,1);
                parameter Real[medium_nc] c_in (each unit="kg/m3") 
                                = {1.0*k for k in 1:medium_nc}     "Feed inlet conc";                        
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 100               "Initial feed volume";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Feed volume";
            equation    
                for i in 1:medium_nc loop
                    outlet.c[i] = c_in[i];
                end for;
                der(V) = outlet.F;               
            end FeedtankType;

            model HarvesttankType
                LiquidCon inlet, port;                                   
                constant Integer medium_nc = size(inlet.c,1);
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 1.0   "Initial harvest liquid volume";
                parameter Real[medium_nc] m_0 
                      (each unit="kg/m3") = zeros(medium_nc)       "Initial substance mass";
                Real[medium_nc] c                                  "Substance conc";
                Real[medium_nc] m 
                      (start=m_0, each fixed=true)                 "Substance mass";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Harvest liquid volume";
            equation
                for i in 1:medium_nc loop
                    der(m[i]) = inlet.c[i]*inlet.F;
                    c[i] = m[i]/V;
                    port.c[i] = c[i];
                end for;
                der(V) = inlet.F;               
            end HarvesttankType;
        end Equipment;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    //     Control 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Control
            block FixValueType
                RealOutput out;
                parameter Real val=0;
            equation
                out = val;
            end FixValueType;
        end Control;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Adaptation of package Equipment to Medium3 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment3
            extends DEMO_v20.Equipment(redeclare package Medium=Medium3);
        end Equipment3;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        model Test
            package medium = DEMO_v20.Medium3;                     // Not accessible in FMU though
            constant String name = medium.name;                    // But name here is accessible
            Equipment3.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment3.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Equipment3.PumpType pump;
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
        end Test;

    end DEMO_v20;
```

And the corresponding application code d20_app7.mo

```
    encapsulated package d20_app7 

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        package Medium7
            import M2 = DEMO_v20.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name = "Seven components"                            "Medium name", 
                nc = 7                                                "Number of substances",
                mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30,40,50,60,70})                    "Substance weight");
            constant Integer C = 3                                    "Substance index";
            constant Integer D = 4                                    "Substance index";    
            constant Integer E = 5                                    "Substance index";    
            constant Integer F = 6                                    "Substance index";    
            constant Integer G = 7                                    "Substance index";    
        end Medium7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Adaptation of library DEMO_v20 to Medium7 and including a new model SensorX 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment7
            extends DEMO_v20.Equipment(redeclare package Medium=Medium7);
            model SensorX
                LiquidCon probe;
                RealOutput out;
                constant Integer component                            "Component measured";         
            equation
                probe.F = 0;
                out = probe.c[component];
            end SensorX;            
        end Equipment7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import DEMO_v20.Control;

        model Test
            package medium = Medium7;                                // Not accessible in FMU though
            constant String name = medium.name;                      // But name here is accessible
            Equipment7.PumpType pump;
            Equipment7.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment7.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Equipment7.SensorX sensor(component = medium.G);               
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
            connect(sensor.probe, harvesttank.port);
        end Test;

    end d20_app7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested both `DEMO_v20.mo` and `d20_app7.mo` in Dymola Version 2018 (64-bit), 2017-04-10.

Loading the file `DEMO_v20.mo` gives the error,

```
<medium declaration> (line 137, column 27: C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/DEMO_v20.mo)

medium already declared on line 135.
```

And running `DEMO_v20.Test` gives,

```
Translation of DEMO_v20.Test:

For variable feedtank.medium_nc
declared in class DEMO_v20.Equipment.FeedtankType, C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/DEMO_v20.mo at line 77, and used in component feedtank.

The variability of the definition equation:
feedtank.medium_nc = size(feedtank.outlet.c, 1);
is higher than the declared variability of the variables.

For variable harvesttank.medium_nc
declared in class DEMO_v20.Equipment.HarvesttankType, C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/DEMO_v20.mo at line 91, and used in component harvesttank.

The variability of the definition equation:
harvesttank.medium_nc = size(harvesttank.inlet.c, 1);
is higher than the declared variability of the variables.

Basic type inconsistencies detected.

Translation aborted.

ERRORS have been issued.
```

Running `d20_app7.Test` gives,

```
Translation of d20_app7.Test:

Encapsulation of d20_app7
prevented us from finding DEMO_v20 in global scope.

Missing base class DEMO_v20.Equipment
the class DEMO_v20.Equipment exists, but Modelica is case-sensitive and uses scoping
File: C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/d20_app7.mo, line 46
Context: d20_app7.Equipment7

Component type specifier Equipment7.PumpType not found
File: C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/d20_app7.mo, line 67
Component context: pump
Component declared as Equipment7.PumpType pump in d20_app7.Test

Component type specifier Equipment7.FeedtankType not found
File: C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/d20_app7.mo, line 68
Component context: feedtank
Component declared as Equipment7.FeedtankType feedtank in d20_app7.Test

Component type specifier Equipment7.HarvesttankType not found
File: C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/d20_app7.mo, line 69
Component context: harvesttank
Component declared as Equipment7.HarvesttankType harvesttank in d20_app7.Test

Component type specifier LiquidCon not found
File: C:/Users/adeas31/Desktop/d20_app7.mo, line 49
Component context: sensor.probe
Component declared as LiquidCon probe in d20_app7.Equipment7.SensorX

WARNINGS have been issued.

ERRORS have been issued.
```

Hope that helps.